# Unable to run the puppeter script on linkeding sales navigator

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, browser, puppeteer

I am using the javascript puppeter library to login into linkedin sales navigator using the below code

```
const page = await browser.newPage();

                // set larger browser height so that the max of 10 results is shown per page
                page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 1200 });
                console.log('page view port setup');

                await page.goto('https://www.linkedin.com/sales/login');

                const EMAIL_SELECTOR = '#username';
                const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '#password';
                const BUTTON_SELECTOR = '#app__container > main > div > form > div.login__form_action_container > button';

                console.log('clicking page')
                await page.click(EMAIL_SELECTOR);
                await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.linkedin);
                console.log('password change');
                await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
                await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.password);

                console.log('click the button');
                await page.click(BUTTON_SELECTOR);
```

When i executing the snippet I am getting the error
[image: Error image]
But what i found is the node is present in the ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the form is in an iframe. You have to select that first in puppeteer:

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();

                // set larger browser height so that the max of 10 results is shown per page
                page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 1200 });
                console.log('page view port setup');

                await page.goto('https://www.linkedin.com/sales/login');

                const iframe = await (await page.$('iframe')).contentFrame()

                const EMAIL_SELECTOR = '#username';
                const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '#password';
                const BUTTON_SELECTOR = '#app__container > main > div > form > div.login__form_action_container > button';

                console.log('clicking page')
                await iframe.click(EMAIL_SELECTOR);
                await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.linkedin);
                console.log('password change');
                await iframe.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
                await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.password);

                console.log('click the button');
                await iframe.click(BUTTON_SELECTOR);
```